# Mediaelement.js support for Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, html5-video, flash, mediaelement.js

I am currently trying to use mediaelement.js as a solution for full cross browser support for my HTML5 videos. I used this Tutorial ( http://vimeo.com/44576115 ) in order to get the mediaelement working and it is working fine on Safari,Chrome,FF and IE9. I have tried it on IE8 and it is giving me a white screen without any video at all, I assuming this is a flash fallback failure ? I also need the video to have a flexible width so that It will fit in a responsive layout. I am starting to get totally lost on what I am running into as an issue. Could somebody please provide me with a "template" or a donation of tried and proven html5 video code which will work in all browsers including older IE browsers and IOS devices Ipad, Android etc? This will really help me a great deal and if anyone can help it will be very much appreciated.

Thank you very much.

This is my code for the video element, I have doubled checked all the directories to ensure correct linking.

```
<div class="vidcon">

<video width="640" height="360" controls="controls" preload="none">
<!-- MP4 for Safari, IE9, iPhone, iPad, Android, and Windows Phone 7 -->
<source type="video/mp4" src="darrel-vid.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
<!-- WebM/VP8 for Firefox4, Opera, and Chrome -->
<source type="video/webm" src="darrel-vid.webm" type="video/webm" />
<!-- Ogg/Vorbis for older Firefox and Opera versions -->
<source type="video/ogg" src="darrel-vid.ogv" type="video/ogg" />

<!-- Flash fallback for non-HTML5 browsers without JavaScript -->
<object width="640" height="360" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="mediaelement/build/flashmediaelement.swf">
    <param name="movie" value="flashmediaelement.swf" />
    <param name="flashvars" value="controls=true&poster=Darrel-poster.jpg&file=darrel-vid.mp4" />
    <!-- Image as a last resort -->
</object>
</video>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In IE8 it uses the Flash fallback.
Please make sure, in the flashvars the path of the mp4 is correct.

Please post your code.